# Can Access CSS File By URL, But Not From HTML

Tags: css, spring, dojo, spring-roo

I have a Spring App with ThymeLeaf and Dojo that is causing me a problem.  The CSS files are showing up aborted in Firebug when I reference them from my HTML file.  However, when I go directly to the file by putting a copy of the CSS URL in the address bar, it works.  In addition, the Dojo code works, but it fails when it gets to the CSS file.  So, I have tried a CSS link only and with Dojo and both fail.  I have searched this one for hours, but I cannot find anyone else having this problem.

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Comment: Figured out the issue. I turned on debug on the server and tested a JS and CSS file. They both behaved the same from the server perspective and it looked like the CSS file was being sent correctly. So, I tried IE and it worked fine. After reinstalling Firefox, the software works as expected. Wish I had figured out this issue earlier.

Comment: consider self-answering your question, e.g. provide your comment as answer and accept it. This gives better visibility that this issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. I turned on debug on the server and tested a JS and CSS file. They both behaved the same from the server perspective and it looked like the CSS file was being sent correctly. So, I tried IE and it worked fine. After reinstalling Firefox, the software works as expected. Wish I had figured out this issue earlier